# Correct use of the this pointer in javascript for callbacks in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am a relatively experienced c# (and before that c++ Win32) developer, I am new to javascript and have a question regarding the `this` pointer.

I am using knockout.js, and one function called subscribe accepts a `this` variable, that will be set inside the callback function.

From my way of thinking from the Win32 days and C#, on any callback function i want a scope object which contains my state.

In this case I have use the `this` javascript thing to set my callback scope.

My questions are:

1. Now everything works (**[full fiddle here if you are
   interested](http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/DTdyM/25/)**), but have I done something terrible?
2. Is there any reason `this` is used instead of passing in an explicit
   scope variable as a parameter (that would make things easier to understand as
   for me, this makes the workings kind of hidden).
3. What is the intended use for `this`?

From http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html it says:

**The subscribe function accepts three parameters: callback is the function that is called whenever the notification happens, target (optional) defines the value of this in the callback function, and event (optional; default is "change") is the name of the event to receive notification for. Example below**

```
myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
    alert("The person's previous name is " + oldValue);
}, null, "beforeChange");
```

My code snippet below:

```
var computedOptions = createComputedDepdency(viewModel[option.requires.target],option.data);
viewModel[option.optionsName] = computedOptions;

console.log("making callback scope object for: " + option.optionsName );
var callbackScope = {
    callbackName: option.optionsName,
    options: computedOptions,
    selectedValue: viewModel[option.selectedName]
};

// when the list of available options changes, set the selected property to the first option
computedOptions.subscribe(function () {
    var scope = this;
    console.log("my object: %o", scope);   
    scope.selectedValue(scope.options()[0].sku);
    console.log("in subscribe function for..." + scope.callbackName);
},callbackScope);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `var scope = this;` be outside the callback...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a semantic note:

The scope of a function is not related to `this` word. The `context` is related to `this`. The scope is related to the accessibility of variables and functions inside another function.

When you try to read a variable outside the function where it's declared, then you trying to access to a var outside its scope. So you cannot do it because the var is inside a scope not accessible from current position.

> Now everything works (full fiddle here if you are interested), but have I done something terrible?

If it works, it's not so terrible :-)

> Is there any reason this is used instead of passing in an explicit scope variable as a parameter (that would make things easier to understand as for me, this makes the workings kind of hidden).

a fast read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

> In javascript the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called.

In one way this approach could save annoying passage of context as argument: in a well documented library, the `this` use is very intituitive.
In other cases, I agree when you change continually context in your app without a rigorous logic, it could be confused.

> What is the intended use for this?

We should always remember how and when the javascript is born. It was born for browser in order to interact with the DOM.

For this purpose, the context has sense that change based of which element call the function.

For example:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click',_clickHandler);
}

function _clickHandler() {
    this.innerHTML = "clicked";
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/AYBsL/1/

This is an example to how is useful the implicit change of context in javascript.

You could do this also for user-defined function: when you call a function you could change the context:

```
_clickHandler.call(divs[0]); // simulate click of first div
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript 'this' refers to the object that called your function. Only in a situation when you use 'new' keyword you can expect it to point to the current object (function).

```
var MyObject = function () {
  this.hello = function () { console.log(this); }
}

var instance = new MyObject();
```

There is a way to make sure that this is always what you expect and that is creating a variable to store the correct reference for you and use that instead of this... in your example it would be similar to this...

```
computedOptions = function () {
  var that = this;
}

computedOptions.subscribe(function () {
    console.log("my object: %o", scope);   
    scope.selectedValue(that.options()[0].sku);
    console.log("in subscribe function for..." + that.callbackName);
},callbackScope);
```

[MDN JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) would inevitably explaing it more better then myself, have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix scope and `this`. `this` is supposed to mimic classical-oop languages like java or++, that is to keep the reference to an instance object. But it can be used just to execute arbitrary function on a given context using `.apply()` or `.call`.

What about scope, you don't have to do anything to pass the scope to a function, since the outer scope becomes automatically accessible inside function. You should read about closures - it's the best part of javascript.